# PHP ucwords/ucfirst error on echo but works on var_dump

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, uppercase

Im using Codeigniter, Please take a look below:

```
<?php 
    $class = $this->router->fetch_class();
    $method = $this->router->fetch_method();

    var_dump($class);
    var_dump(ucwords($class));
    var_dump(ucwords(strtolower($class)));
?>

<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>

    <!-- this one is not working -->
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url($class) ?>"><?php echo $page_alias ? $page_alias : ucwords(strtolower($class)) ?></a></li>
    <!-- end of this one is not working -->


    <li class="active"><?php echo ucwords($method); ?></li>
</ol>
```

the string on the ***var_dump()*** works, but in this section its not working at all

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url($class) ?>"><?php echo $page_alias ? $page_alias : ucwords(strtolower($class)) ?></a></li>
```

I have try remove the ***strtolower*** like this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url($class) ?>"><?php echo $page_alias ? $page_alias : ucwords($class) ?></a></li>
```

but still wont work, Anybody have the same error here? thank you

Comment: In codeigniter controller class name in url should be in small, else you will get not found

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thank you, but unfortunately that's not what Im ask, I want the first character on the class name to become uppercase, can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semicolon at the end of statement
replace

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url($class) ?>"><?php echo $page_alias ? $page_alias : ucwords($class) ?></a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url($class);?>"><?php echo ($page_alias ? $page_alias : ucwords($class)); ?></a></li>
```

Comment: still not working, I have try this before, but thanks

Comment: what is output of var_dump($class);;

Comment: string 'posts' (length=5), the only error is the posts didn't get capitalized

Comment: I want 'posts' to be 'Posts'

Comment: The only error is the posts still printed in lowercase

Comment: have you checked your condition is true echo $page_alias; i think it's true and printing alias

Comment: Yes that's my problem, I didn't pay attention to that part, now it works, many thanks sir ...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe $class is not a string.

Try :

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url($class) ?>"><?php echo $page_alias ? $page_alias : strtolower(var_export($class, TRUE)) ?></a></li>
```

Comment: $class is the name of the class I defined from $this->router->fetch_class() method, not working sir

Answer (score -1):

you can try this way

```
$class = $this->router->fetch_class();
$nameClass = (string)$class;
echo ucfirst($nameClass);
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for advice, i answer this way due the time, next time i'll do right ^^